# Homebrew package installation with homebrew installed keg-only libraries? How to do it?

Tags: macos, curl, openssl, homebrew

I'd like to install curl with openssl via homebrew. I did it like this

`brew install curl --with-openssl`

Before that I installed the homebrew openssl, which is version 1.0.2 at the moment. Since this openssl is keg-only and Apple provides also an outdated system version of openssl, Homebrew suggests to set the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable like `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/pkgconfig"`, which I did. Then if I run `pkg-config --list-all |## Heading ##grep openssl` it finds openssl. My problem is that when I then run `brew install curl --with-openssl` and `curl -V` it still installs without openssl but uses the secure transport instead. What could be the reason?

```
curl 7.61.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0) libcurl/7.61.0 SecureTransport zlib/1.2.5
Release-Date: 2018-07-11 
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz UnixSockets
```

Thanks!

Comment: The [`curl` brew formula](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/curl.rb#L66) should figure out by itself where the brew-installed version of `openssl` resides. From that, you can see that there should be no need for you to set `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` manually. What you are trying works for me. When you run your `brew install curl` command and look at the output, what does it tell you concerning the arguments to `./configure`? Mine says (among others) `--with-ssl=/usr/local/opt/openssl`, which is the right place.

Comment: Thanks, you're right. I ran `brew uninstall`and then `brew install --with-openssl`and it didn't run ./configure again. `brew reinstall` solved it. Apparently there is a difference, which isn't mentioned in the man-page.

Comment: Glad your figured it out. Since I had some useful information at hand by now anyway, I summarized it in an answer for the sake of future readers. Happy brewing :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you already resolved the issue, I am adding some information here that might have been useful for you to know.

The [brew formula for `curl`](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/curl.rb) is fairly easy to read. You can also find it locally via `brew formula curl`. With regard to `openssl`, it shows you the following:

```
    # cURL has a new firm desire to find ssl with PKG_CONFIG_PATH instead of using
    # "--with-ssl" any more. "when possible, set the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment
    # variable instead of using this option". Multi-SSL choice breaks w/o using it.
    if MacOS.version < :mountain_lion || build.with?("openssl") || build.with?("nghttp2")
      ENV.prepend_path "PKG_CONFIG_PATH", "#{Formula["openssl"].opt_lib}/pkgconfig"
      args << "--with-ssl=#{Formula["openssl"].opt_prefix}"
      args << "--with-ca-bundle=#{etc}/openssl/cert.pem"
      args << "--with-ca-path=#{etc}/openssl/certs"
    else
      args << "--with-darwinssl"
      args << "--without-ca-bundle"
      args << "--without-ca-path"
    end
```

So no need to adjust `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` manually yourself, the formula will do it for you by pointing to the brew-installed version of `openssl`. (It is unclear to me though why both `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` and `--with-ssl` are set, since `curl` seems to prefer the former, as quoted in the comment lines.)

The `args` mentioned here should show up when you run `brew install` as follows (removing some uninteresting output and reformatted somewhat for clarity to make the relevant args start on a new line):

```
$ brew install curl --with-openssl
==> Downloading https://curl.haxx.se/download/curl-7.61.0.tar.bz2
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> ./configure --disable-silent-rules --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/curl/7.61.0
        --with-ssl=/usr/local/opt/openssl --with-ca-bundle=/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem --with-ca-path=/usr/local/etc/open
==> make install
```

The `--with-ssl` argument should point to your brew installation of openssl. If this is not what it looks like for you, you can start debugging the formula...

Apparently using `brew reinstall` did the trick for you.

Comment: FYI you should do `brew install curl-openssl` instead, as the Homebrew team has removed all options for the cURL formula.